# Is there a way to display a message at login screen if a device is not found on Windows?

Tags: windows, powershell, authentication

I am looking for a way if we can display a message on the computer screen if the mouse or keyboard is not detected by the system.

I can get the status fine using the PowerShell however was wondering if this can used for constant monitoring.

```bsh
if ((Get-WmiObject Win32_PointingDevice | Where-Object {$_.Description -match 'hid'}).Count -gt 0) {
    Write-Host "Mouse is connected"
} else {
    Write-Host "Mouse not found"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it. How could a Windows system possibly be secure if it would be possible to run an arbitrary powershell script before logon?

The credentials are an essential part of WMF and PowerShell.